# Secure web routes with laravel passport token

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-passport

I am newbie with laravel.

I understand that in order to protect routes, you have to first check if a user is authenticated and a session is made. thus, we apply auth middleware in the web routes.

However, I am trying to implement laravel passport and now I am not able to proceed to my routes anymore since I have been authenticated using the passport.

My question is that is it possible to secure the web routes with passport token instead of laravel session? and if so, how one should do it?

Thanks, sorry for english, not native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel passport is for API routes not for web routes you can use laravel session for web
for more details read it's documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport

Comment: So what I need to do is use both passport and laravel session?

Comment: For web use only laravel session

Comment: How exactly I do this after successfull api call?